# Can a Spark accumulator be faster than a aggregateByKey?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I've written an algorithm in Pyspark which uses `aggregateByKey` to get a big list of `(key, python_obj)` (the `python_obj` itself is a not so small Python class).

Theoretically I could implement the same with accumulators by making a huge dictionary, right?

Is it worth the effort or are accumulators meant for a different use-case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be border cases where accumulators can be faster but in general the answer is negative. Simplifying things a little bit implementing `aggregateByKey` using accumulators is equivalent to calling `collect` on partial results for each partition and processing final output locally on the driver machine:

```
rdd.mapPartitions(_.fold(zero)(combineOp)).collect.reduce(mergeOp)
```

Even if you ignore accumulator reliability issues and slightly awkward API this simply makes driver machine a bottleneck and may be not feasible in general case.